# Setting parameter equal to a variable in local function in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-oauth

I am working on a twitter API application and I need to use the user's access token and secret token to fetch their timeline

The twitter passport strategy gets me the tokens as follows:

```
passport.use(new Strategy({
consumerKey: '##################',
consumerSecret: '####################',
callbackURL: 'http://localhost:8000/twitter/callback'
}, function(token, tokenSecret, profile, callback){
    return callback(null, profile);
}));
```

If I console.log(token) and tokensecret inside the function, I see the token in my console however I am trying to save these tokens to a global variable to use in my other .js file. I essentially need to plug it into this :

```
var client = new Twitter({
consumer_key: '###########',
consumer_secret: '################',
access_token_key: 'token',
access_token_secret: 'tokenSecret'
});
```

Is this possible or a way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can initialize your Twitter client into the function and assign this to a global variable in order to be used outside. If you want to use it in other modules, you need to pass it them as parameters of the functions called